# Uninstall Ubuntu 18.10 when alongside 18.04

Tags: 18.10

I've been running 18.04 quite successfully.  I installed 18.10 alongside to evaluate it.
I'm sticking with 18.04.  How do I uninstall 18.10?

Comment: 18.04 is LTS and supported until 2023. 18.10 is not and End of Life a long time ago, shouldn't be used.

Comment: Install Grub from version 18.04 - Edit Grub in session 18.04 and remove option from version 18.10 - Remove installation from version 18.10.

Comment: I have 18.10 on the same partition as 18.04.  I installed it using the "alongside" option.  I don't want to risk losing anything on 18.04.  Is there a proc for removal that will do this?